# Spring + Hibernate wrong entity values on save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

When I save a new entity on a MariaDB database with the PK and another field auto generated by the database, the entity is persisted correctly but the instance returned by Hibernate has inverted the value.

Thanks for the help

Example code 1:

```
enter your code here
```

Example code 2:

```
enter your code here
```

Comment: Please don't post text/code as images but post the text itself (and format it nicely).

Comment: `@GeneratedValue` only works on `@Id` columns it doesn't work for other columns. So your code is just not going to work. So what you see is what you should expect (id being filled, number not).

Comment: Sorry, I try to modify the post correctly but editor refused to save : "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code"

Comment: Try inserting the code using that format @Cedric